# Python XML to CSV lookup values in second dataframe and list multiple values

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

This is related to [Python XML to CSV help for novice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69098095/python-xml-to-csv-help-for-novice).  Thank you to @aneroid for helping me get started.

I'm able to get my columns and rows out, and have two remaining issues that I don't know what to search for to find answers.

Remaining Issue 1: My XML has up to 20 values for some attributes. I want to list these in a single comma-separated string. See "Years" in my example below.

I found some things on grouping, but I don't think that will work since I'm only getting the first value out of my XML. I need to list all of the matching values from the XML. Plus my full report has 120 columns, so would I need to list all the columns to group by?

(UPDATE START) I researched lxml.etree and can now get this:

```
['2019', '2020']
```

I've updated the Python below. If anyone can help with the homestretch of getting this to just 2019, 2020, that's be awesome. Issue 2 is similar - just need to pull values from the dictionary. (UPDATE END)

Remaining Issue 2: The XML lists related things by name, and then lists them again as separate "row"s with additional attributes for the things. I need to include a value of one of those additional attributes in the report. In my sample Python, I create a second dataframe, called thing_df that includes the names and the ID attribute. I need to match the thing name in the coll_df to the thing name in the thing_df to get its thing_id and add that to the coll_df.

I have found some things on merging datasets, but those examples seem to be for merging what I call collections in my example, and not for what I'm looking for.

Desired output:

```
,Collection item,ITEM-ID,ATTRIB-1,PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME,ATTRIB-2,PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME,RELATED-THING-1 id,RELATED-THING-2 IDs,Years
0,name of Item 1,item_000001,Yes,name of person 1,Yes,name of person 2,thing_000745,"thing_000783, thing_000803","2019, 2020"
```

Python (UPDATED):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Importing the required libraries
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import lxml.etree as Xet
import pandas as pd

#Define main collection columns and rows for dataframe
coll_cols = ["Collection item", "ITEM-ID", "ATTRIB-1", "PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME" ,
        "ATTRIB-2", "PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME", "RELATED-THING-1 id",
        "RELATED-THING-2 IDs", "Years"]
coll_rows = []
#Define thing lookup dataframe columns and rows
thing_cols = ["Thing Name", "Thing ID"]
thing_rows = []

# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('sample.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()
for row in root:
    # Create thing lookup dataframe
    if (
            row.findtext('type') == "THING-TYPE-1" or
            row.findtext('type') == "THING-TYPE-2"
            ):
        thing_id = row.findtext("THING-ID")
        thing_name = row.findtext("name")
        thing_rows.append({"Thing Name": thing_name,
                           "Thing ID": thing_id})
        thing_df = pd.DataFrame(thing_rows, columns=thing_cols)
    # Find only collection items
    if row.findtext('type') != "COLLECTION-ITEM":
        continue
    # Define values for collection item dataframe
    name = row.findtext("name", "Missing name")
    item_id = row.findtext("ITEM-ID", "Missing item ID")
    attrib_1 = row.findtext("ATTRIB-1", "Missing attribute 1")
    p1_name = row.findtext("./PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME/result/row/name")
    attrib_2 = row.findtext("ATTRIB-2", "Missing attribute 2")
    p2_name = row.findtext("./PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME/result/row/name")
    relat_thing1 = row.xpath("./RELATED-THING-1/result/row/name/text()")
    #relat_thing1_id = look up relat_thing1 in infr_df as "Thing Name" \
    #    and return "Thing ID"
    relat_thing2 = row.xpath("./RELATED-THING-2/result/row/name/text()")
    #relat_thing2_id = look up every relat_thing2 in infr_df as "Thing Name" \
    #    and return all "Thing ID"
    years = row.xpath("./RPTD-HIST-CODE/result/row/name/text()")

    coll_rows.append({"Collection item": name,
                 "ITEM-ID": item_id,
                 "ATTRIB-1": attrib_1,
                 "PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME": p1_name,
                 "ATTRIB-2": attrib_2,
                 "PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME": p2_name,
                 #"RELATED-THING-1 id": relat_thing1_id,
                 #"RELATED-THING-2 IDs": relat_thing2_ids,
                 "Years": years
})

coll_df = pd.DataFrame(coll_rows, columns=coll_cols)

# Writing dataframe to csv
coll_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved all but looking in a dataframe for "Thing Name" to get "Thing ID." I'll post a new and simpler question focusing on that.

Here is the new Python that resolves my Remaining Issue 1 and half my Remaining Issue 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Importing the required libraries
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import lxml.etree as Xet
import pandas as pd

#Define main collection columns and rows for dataframe
coll_cols = ["Collection item", "ITEM-ID", "ATTRIB-1", "PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME" ,
        "ATTRIB-2", "PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME", "RELATED-THING-1 id",
        "RELATED-THING-2 IDs", "Years"]
coll_rows = []
#Define thing lookup dataframe columns and rows
thing_cols = ["Thing Name", "Thing ID"]
thing_rows = []

# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('sample.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()
for row in root:
    # Create thing lookup dataframe
    if (
            row.findtext('type') == "THING-TYPE-1" or
            row.findtext('type') == "THING-TYPE-2"
            ):
        thing_id = row.findtext("THING-ID")
        thing_name = row.findtext("name")
        thing_rows.append({"Thing Name": thing_name,
                           "Thing ID": thing_id})
        thing_df = pd.DataFrame(thing_rows, columns=thing_cols)
    # Find only collection items
    if row.findtext('type') != "COLLECTION-ITEM":
        continue
    # Define values for collection item dataframe
    name = row.findtext("name", "Missing name")
    item_id = row.findtext("ITEM-ID", "Missing item ID")
    attrib_1 = row.findtext("ATTRIB-1", "Missing attribute 1")
    p1_name = row.findtext("./PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME/result/row/name")
    attrib_2 = row.findtext("ATTRIB-2", "Missing attribute 2")
    p2_name = row.findtext("./PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME/result/row/name")
    relat_thing1_items = row.xpath("./RELATED-THING-1/result/row/name/text()")
    if len(relat_thing1_items) > 0:
        relat_thing1 = ', '.join(relat_thing1_items)
    else:
        relat_thing1 = ""
    #relat_thing1_id = look up relat_thing1 in infr_df as "Thing Name" \
    #    and return "Thing ID"
    relat_thing2_items = row.xpath("./RELATED-THING-2/result/row/name/text()")
    if len(relat_thing2_items) > 0:
        relat_thing2 = ', '.join(relat_thing2_items)
    else:
        relat_thing2 = ""
    #relat_thing2_id = look up every relat_thing2 in infr_df as "Thing Name" \
    #    and return all "Thing ID"
    year_items = row.xpath("./RPTD-HIST-CODE/result/row/name/text()")
    if len(year_items) > 0:
        years = ', '.join(year_items)
    else:
        years = ""

    coll_rows.append({"Collection item": name,
                 "ITEM-ID": item_id,
                 "ATTRIB-1": attrib_1,
                 "PERSON-TYPE-1-NAME": p1_name,
                 "ATTRIB-2": attrib_2,
                 "PERSON-TYPE-2-NAME": p2_name,
                 "RELATED-THING-1 id": relat_thing1,
                 "RELATED-THING-2 IDs": relat_thing2,
                 "Years": years
})

coll_df = pd.DataFrame(coll_rows, columns=coll_cols)

# Writing dataframe to csv
coll_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```